# One Action Button for Multiple Dependent Events in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed a Shiny app that allows the user conditional selection of some dependent events. A very simplified toy example is below to help illustrate my question/problem.

In my real problem, the server code contains multiple computationally expensive procedures that are optional to run. There is a "baseline" function that must run to produce output and then firstObject or secondObject take that as input and produce more output if it is selected by the user to do so.

Each function can take upwards of 30 to 40 minutes. So, I wrote the code to allow the user to select using the checkInputBox which functions they want to run and then after selecting them, there is a single action button that runs them all allowing the user to leave and let the process take its course over many hours. This was more convenient than having an actionButton associated with each possible event.

The code below is successful in yielding all the desired output. But, I am not sure from a design point of view if it is "right". In my toy example, the code is simple, but suppose the code for baseObject takes 30 minutes to run. While baseObject is running, the code for firstObject and secondObject were also executed because they depend on the same action button. But, they cannot do anything until the function for baseObject is done. Similarly secondObject cannot do anything until firstObject is done.

Again, this all works and yields the correct output (in my real code as well as in the toy code). But, is there a way to maintain the single action button, but for firstObject to not do anything UNTIL baseline Object has produced its output and then secondObject would wait for firstObject to yield its output if the user selected it.

My worry is that I am creating additional computational overhead in the firstObject is trying to do something it cannot do until baseObject is done and it is cycling over and over until it can properly execute.

I know I can create different action buttons. For instance I could create an action button for baseline and then the user could wait until it is done and then click the action button for firstObject and so on. But, functionally this would not work as in the real problem this allows the entire selected process to run, which can take hours and the user does not need to be in front of their machine.

Thank you and I hope this code helps illustrate the problem as I have described it.

```
ui <- {
  fluidPage(
    h3('Run Stuff'),
    checkboxInput("runModel1", "Model 1"),
    checkboxInput("runModel2", "Model 2"),
    actionButton('runAll', 'Run Models'),
    verbatimTextOutput("out1"),
    verbatimTextOutput("out2")
    )
}

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

baseObject <- eventReactive(input$runAll, {
    if(input$runModel1){
        runif(100)
    }
})

firstObject <- eventReactive(input$runAll, {
    if(input$runModel1){
        runif(100) + baseObject()
    }
})

secondObject <- eventReactive(input$runAll, {
    if(input$runModel2){
        runif(100) + firstObject()
    }
})

output$out1 <- renderPrint({
if (input$runModel1)
    firstObject()
})

output$out2 <- renderPrint({
if (input$runModel2)
    secondObject()
})
} # end server


shinyApp(ui, server) #run
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to remember about reactive expressions:

1. Reactive expressions are lazy and only execute when called by something else. This is different from observers, which execute immediately any time their dependencies change.
2. Reactive expression results are cached. As long as their dependencies have not changed, subsequent calls won't cause the expression to re-execute, but instead retrieve the cached value.

Based on these two points, I don't think you have a problem and your example does what you're looking for. With both checkboxes ticked, each reactive expression would only run once per action button click.

Although I can suggest removing the unnecessary if statements in the `eventReactive`s. That would allow the user to only check `runModel2` and have all its dependencies run properly. Modified example below - I also added some `message(...)` statements so you can see the execution flow in the R console.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h3('Run Stuff'),
  checkboxInput("runModel1", "Model 1"),
  checkboxInput("runModel2", "Model 2"),
  actionButton('runAll', 'Run Models'),
  verbatimTextOutput("out1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("out2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  baseObject <- eventReactive(input$runAll, {
    message("calculating baseObject...")
    result <- runif(100)
    message("...baseObject done")
    return(result)
  })

  firstObject <- eventReactive(input$runAll, {
    message("calculating firstObject...")
    result <- runif(100) + baseObject()
    message("...firstObject done")
    return(result)
  })

  secondObject <- eventReactive(input$runAll, {
    message("calculating secondObject...")
    result <- runif(100) + firstObject()
    message("...secondObject done")
    return(result)
  })

  output$out1 <- renderPrint({
    if (input$runModel1)
      firstObject()
  })

  output$out2 <- renderPrint({
    if (input$runModel2)
      secondObject()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```